# Springboot REST API Testcase passing in local but failing in build

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have a test case class something like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class sampleTests {

   when(test.getUrl()).thenReturn("http://localhost:8080/sampletest");

 @Test
  public void getEndpoint() throws Exception {
        webTestClient.get().uri("/sampletest").exchange().expectStatus().isOk().expectBody().consumeWith(System.out::println).json(expectedBody);

         }

}
```

This is passing in local, but got failed with the following error when executed in the azure DevOps pipeline.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR>
```

Any insights on the same will be much appreciated.

Comment: you don't get any other exception stacktrace? Btw, it's not a good idea to have `DEFINED_PORT`, it could be random port too..

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Eugene.  No other potential traces are thrown. If I am not using a defined port, how can I make it target the 8080 port ? Let me try it out, configuring that in application.properties.

Comment: without a stacktrace, this is impossible to diagnose, I am sure you know that. You don't "need" to target 8080 usually, what if there is some other service that is running on 8080 on that host? That's the entire point of `RANDOM_PORT` and then you use annotation `@LocalServerPort` (or `@Value("${local.server.port}"`) if you are on a spring version that does not have that yet

Comment: Thanks Eugene.I have defined the port number in application.yaml as 8080, and it's taken by default during the execution in local. But why can't it take it in the build ?

I tried using Random Port and  @Value("${local.server.port}") but still the default port only taken because /sampletest executes the snippet where it catches the port on the fly from application.yaml.

I have seen the trace and port is the only problem. If I am able to make the get call get this random port number on the fly, I believe it will do it. Trying that now.

Comment: after you have the port in your test class, for example `@Autowired private WebTestClient webClient;`, you need to use it in the testing code, for example: `webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:{port}/actuator/health", this.port)`